# php dynamic checkbox with mysql support

Tags: php

How to get value from databases in our dynamic checkbox in php without refreshing page and without using ajax?

I  have tried in same page with php logic and html.

```php
if($conn)
{
    $sql="select * from contacts where for_id='".$chk."'";
    $result=$conn->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows>0)
    {
        while($_row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"".$_row['id']."\">" . $_row['id'] ."&nbsp;".$_row['name'].'&nbsp;'.$_row['contact'].'</br>';
            $id=$_row['id'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without ajax you're pretty limited since php is a serverside language and therefore all changes need to be made by the server and with a page reload. You can work with frames if there is not other possibility but that's just an idea. I don't really know how it works out with php.

Comment: can you explain , what you wants and what are you doing and what are you getting?

Comment: I was just asking add submit button and entries of database without using ajax and auto refreshed.